# Objects of type prcomp not supported by autoplot

Tags: r, pca, decision-tree

I have a data frame of multiple columns. I want to carry out PCA and classification with decision trees to check if information on il.count.ratio to une.count.ratio can actually help to differentiate the two professions.

```
Profession    il.count.ratio   elle.count.ratio    un.count.ratio   une.count.ratio
secretary      1.7241              1.3514             1.473            0.7380
secretary      0.0000              2.8736             2.8536           0.8370
driver         1.7065              0.0000             0.0000           0.7380
driver         0.5284              1.4733             0.7380           0.5280
```

output is : Error in `autoplot()`:
! Objects of type prcomp not supported by autoplot.

someone know what may be the problem ?

```
data %>%
  select(il.count.ratio:une.count.ratio) %>%
  prcomp() %>%
  autoplot(data = data,
           colour = 'Profession',
           loadings = TRUE,
           loadings.colour = "blue",
           loadings.label = TRUE,
           loadings.label.colour = "blue")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use broom's `augment` (for the PCs) and `tidy` (for the loadings) to get a dataframe before `ggplot`ing:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(broom)

data <- tribble(
  ~Profession, ~il.count.ratio, ~elle.count.ratio, ~un.count.ratio, ~une.count.ratio,
  "secretary", 1.7241, 1.3514, 1.473, 0.7380,
  "secretary", 0.0000, 2.8736, 2.8536, 0.8370,
  "driver", 1.7065, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.7380,
  "driver", 0.5284, 1.4733, 0.7380, 0.5280
)

data %>%
  select(il.count.ratio:une.count.ratio) %>%
  prcomp() %>% 
  augment(data) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(.fittedPC1, .fittedPC2, colour = Profession)) +
  geom_point()
```

[image]

```r
  
# Use instead of augment for the loadings
# tidy(matrix = "loadings")
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>